# create user in db with oauth node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, oauth

I've set up express server, i'm using passport.js 
i'm using a local strategy right now where i'm authenticating the user

```
passport.use(new Strategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
  }, (email, password, cb) => {
  db.get().collection('user').findOne({email: email}, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return cb(err)
    }
    if (!user) {
      return cb(null, false)
    }
    if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
      return cb(null, false)
    }
    return cb(null, user)
  })
}))
```

i'm creating user in the router like this:

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  const user = poster.user(req.body)
  if(user){
    db.get().collection('user').insert(user)
    res.send('success')
  }else{
    res.send('error')
  }
  // res.send(req.body)
})
```

my question is that how i can create a user with oauth? Or shall i even create a user in my db when i'm using oauth? I want users to be able to login with facebook, twitter and google.